# Hadoop 2.6.4 Web UI Time Out

Tags: hadoop, amazon-web-services

I installed Hadoop 2.6.4 on my AWS - 4 instance; 1 namenode; 1 secnamenode; 2 slaves. After the installation is completed, I tried seeing the namenode on Web UI using URL ec2-52-90-242-76.compute-1.amazonaws.com:50070 I am getting timed out.. anybody help??

Answer (score 0):

If you are accessing from your system, you need to update your hosts files with IP address along with hostname or you can open directly with IP_address:50070

As well as check below

1. Check Firewall is on or off (Recommended is off)
2. Check Iptables service status (Recommended is stop)
3. Check SELINUX (Recommended is disables)